# Kubernetes: Privileged container in Linux docker-multinode cluster

Tags: ubuntu, containers, kubernetes

(I have looked at some other threads, but apparently the privilege mode is now supported in the latest code, so am wondering if I have hit a bug.)

I have two physical servers: both running Linux (ubuntu), with the latest kubernetes code from github yesterday.

I am running `docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master.sh` (& `worker.sh`).

On Master node:

```
$ kubectl create -f examples/nfs/nfs-server-rc.yaml
The ReplicationController "nfs-server" is invalid. 
spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: forbidden '<*>(0xc208389770)true'
```

Question: Is this supported? Or am I doing something wrong. Or is this a bug, please?

`master.sh` code already has the option `--allow-privileged=true` provided.

These following options were set, but not with a great conviction, and just because I saw some discussion elsewhere setting them.

```
/etc/default/kubelet: 
    `KUBELET_OPTS="--allow_privileged=true"`

/etc/default/kube-apiserver: 
    `KUBE_APISERVER_OPTS="--allow_privileged=true"`
```

Master configuration:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2+", GitVersion:"v1.2.0-alpha.5.833+2e5da8b881e2f5", GitCommit:"2e5da8b881e2f5b6dfb66653acf4aaa1ca1f398e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}

$ docker version
Client:
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 7):

From kubernetes v1.1, any container in a pod can enable privileged mode, using the privileged flag on the SecurityContext of the container spec.

To enable privileged mode nest `privileged:true` inside `securityContext` decleration of the container spec:

```
"securityContext": {
    "privileged": true
```

And as Janet said set `--allow-privileged=true` for both kubelet and kube-apiserver and restart them:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kubelet restart
sudo /etc/init.d/kube-apiserver restart
```

and validate that the flags are changed by using `ps -ef | grep kube` command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `--allow-privileged=true` for both `kubelet` and `kube-apiserver`. It looks like `master.sh` only sets that in `kubelet`. You may modify the file `./cluster/images/hyperkube/master-multi.json` to set `--allow-privileged=true` for apiserver (should be around line 21 to 30) and rebuild `hyperkube` images.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help: changing multi-master.json.

Interestingly, instead of running the multi-node linux example, I ran the hack/local-up-cluster.sh, stand-alone setup.

The error was slightly different:

`/usr/src/kubernetes/examples/nfs# kubectl create -f nfs-server-rc.yaml 
The ReplicationController "nfs-server" is invalid.
spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by policy.`

Comment: Run `ALLOW_PRIVILEGED=true hack/local-up-cluster.sh` when starting the local cluster.

Comment: No luck with the original problem.  But, thanks to you, the second example, i.e. stand alone setup worked.

Comment: Should the original problem be considered a bug? I would appreciate if somebody could reproduce it. Thanks.

Comment: I am also getting same error ..I am running multinode cluster with 2 minions.